# Modal View issue with tab bar controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller and when loading the tab bar controller what I want to do is to load a registration page. Here is my code for this.

```
    RegistrationScreen *registrationScreen = [[RegistrationScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegistrationScreen" bundle:nil];
    [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:registrationScreen animated:FALSE];       
    [registrationScreen release];
```

This works fine. But in my registration page i have a another view which is a read me. I need to load this as another modal view once you click a link in the registration page. However this not triggered. What am I doing wrong here? What should I do to load multiple views on top of tab bar controller?

Thank you

Comment: You should really quote the code that is not working if you want to know what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `RegistrationScreen` is a modal view controller, it shouldn't have `self.tabBarController` or `self.navigationController`.  You can check yourself with NSLog or similar.

It should have `self.parentViewController`.

inside RegistrationScreen.m try:

```
[self.parentViewController.tabBarController presentModalViewController:xxxx]
```

or

```
[self presentModalViewController:xxxx]
```

depending on how your flow works.

Comment: Yes self.tabBarController doesnt work. However I tried [self presentModalViewController:xxxx] but due to crashing issue within the popup view I thought this also has issue. However once I fix that it ended up working for [self presentModalViewController:xxxx]

Answer (score 0):

TabBarController is declared in AppDelegate file. But I don't know how to use this to present modal view in one of the tab bar viewControllers?
[self.parentViewController.tabBarController presentModalViewController:xxxx]

My source code link is [here](http://uploadingit.com/file/k9dgfjipas5bmgbe/Pickers.zip)